# App stop working when trying to load AdMob ads

Tags: android, admob

I have quiz app, and I want to make another quiz app that will be about something else.
I created new project in Android Studio and I copied all code from first quiz app.

Everything works fine, only when I start activity that have AdMob ads, app stops working.
In first quiz app everything works fine, ads are shown normally, but new quiz app stops working when trying to load AdMob ads.
Do you know where could be a problem?

This is what I use in xml file for AdMob ads:

```
        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="id"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Comment: stops working in the sense, app is crashing? hanging? adds r not visible? whats exactly happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check the admob documentation and make sure you have the correct app ID set up in the admob details within your Android.manifest

You may have the ID from the previous app in there which will not work as the package name will be different.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="go"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7897489627187383/885626" />

</RelativeLayout>
```